# pqxx simple code crashed

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

The following code crashed

```
int main()
{
    std::string connstring = "host=* port=* user=* password=* dbname=*";
    pqxx::connection connection(connstring);

    if (connection.is_open()) {
        pqxx::work transaction(connection);
        transaction.exec("SELECT 1;");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With message:

> double free or corruption

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer myself.
The following solution helped:

```
sudo apt-get remove libpq5
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: After two days of running into the same problem (after recreating my VM and installing postgres again), this tend to fixed it. Thank you!